# Solving quadratic congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, congruences

System of equation is : $$ x^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3 $$ $$ x^2 \equiv 4 \mod 5 $$
So, if first equation doesn't have solution what should I do with it?

Comment: Conclude that the system has no solutions.